# Let X, Y be topological spaces and let y ∈ Y . Show that the map i : X → X × Y, i(x) = (x, y) is continuous

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

I have a feeling the solution is to do with the pre image of an open set in XxY being open in X, but I'm not sure how to go about proving it.

Comment: Open sets in $X\times Y$ are unions of sets of the form $U\times V$, where $U$ is open in $X$ and $V$ is open in $Y$; that should help you in thinking about their preimages under $i$.

Comment: I dont really understand the meaning of U x V, i cant visualise the effect of the cross product

Comment: Picture $X$ and $Y$ as lines, like $\Bbb R$; then $X\times Y$ is schematically like $\Bbb R^2$, and $U\times V$ is schematically like an open rectangle in the plane.

Answer (score 1):

You can use that a map ending in a product space is continuous iif its compositions with the projections are continuous.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Take an open set $U \in X\times Y$, and look at the intersection $\big(X\times \{y\}\big) \cap U$.